# Gulp compile multiple scss/js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

It's my first time using Gulp and i'm a little confused as to what I'm doing wrong, my structure being like this:

```
assets
   -> resources
   -> dist
      -> main.css
   -> src
      -> scss/bootstrap
      -> scss/main.scss

      -> js/bootstrap
      -> js/main.js
```

My goal is to create a gulp file that will compile both my JavaScript and my SCSS and output them into "main.css" and "main.js" in /dist.

```
console.log('Starting compiling process...');

const gulp = require('gulp');
const jsmn = require('gulp-uglify');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

let src         = './resources/src';
let dist        = './resources/dist';
let bootstrap   = './node_modules/bootstrap';
let custom      = './resources/src/scss';

//Configure options
let scss = {
    in: [src + 'scss/*'],
    out: dist,
    watch: src + '/scss/*',
    watchjs: src + '/js/*.js',
    sassOps: {
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
        precision: 3,
        errLogToConsole: true,
        includePaths: [bootstrap + '/scss']
    }
};

//Default task
gulp.task('compile', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss.in)
        .pipe(sass(scss.sassOps))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scss.out));
});

gulp.task('compress', function() {
    return gulp.src([src + '/js/*.js'])
        .pipe(jsmn())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch([scss.watchjs, scss.watch], gulp.parallel('compile', 'compress'));
});
```

Right now it compiles my Javascript, though SCSS is an issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple SCSS/JS files you will need to use [gulp concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to combine all file into single file.

this is what i use to generate my CSS file from multiple SCSS file

```
// styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Also i suggest to use [Gulp Autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) as well

Answer (score 0):

Gulp task to compile your scss , add browsers prefixes ,replace urls used in the source files minify and output them into "main.css" in /dist.

```
/* ------------------------------------
Process CSS
------------------------------------ */
gulp.task('processCss', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename('main.css')) // will be prefixed and minified
        .pipe(replace('url("../../', 'url("../'))
        .pipe(stripCssComments({preserve: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And this task is to compile your js files, minify and output them into "main.js" in /dist.

```
gulp.task('processFooterJs', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())   // will be compressed
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Please use npm to install these dependencies

```
gulp-autoprefixer
gulp-concat
gulp-strip-css-comments
gulp-uglify
gulp-rename
gulp-replace
```

and import them in the top of your file like this :

```
    var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        stripCssComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        replace = require('gulp-replace');
```

And it will be done :)

If you have multiple sources for your js files exemple your need to import jquery.js from node modules and index.js from js folder your task will be like this :

```
/* ------------------------------------
Process JS for footer
------------------------------------ */
gulp.task('processFooterJs', function () {
    return gulp.src([    ,
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'js/index.js',
    ])
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I hope this could help you , best wishes :)